# Update SQL tables through php form

Tags: php, mysqli

Query is running however not being sent to SQL server.
My Current Register Script.

```
$link = mysqli_connect("$server", "$user", "$pass", "$webdb");
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, (string) $_POST['username']);
$displayname = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, (string) $_POST['display_name']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, (string) $_POST['email']);
$password = sha1((string) $_POST['password']);
$query="INSERT INTO user (`username`, `nicename`, `email`, `password`)
VALUES ('$username', '$displayname', '$email', '$password', '1')";
mysqli_query($link, $query);
mysqli_close($link);
echo $query;
?>
```

The output I recieve from the Query:

```
INSERT INTO user (username, nicename, email, password) VALUES ('orion5814', 'Orion5814', 'my@abc.com', '72f2ac484bee398758e769530dd56228d905884d', '1')
```

I've checked all my link variables and they're all set correctly as far as having the right information in place, so I don't know where else to go from here. Sorry for all the questions; you can view it at doxramos.org if you think it would help at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query is flawed.  You name 4 columns `(username, nicename, email, password)`, but you list 5 values `('orion5814','Orion5814','my@abc.com','72f2ac484bee398758e769530dd56228d905884d','1')`
If you remove the last value, the query should work.

Also, you could simplify your code by using the object oriented interface to mysqli like this:

```
$username = $link->real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
```

and

```
$link->query($query);
$link->close();
```

You also don't need to explicitly cast the variables as strings since that is done automatically if needed for your code.

Comment: You were correct on that and I also appreciate the input on simplifying strings. On my list of things to do; thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

As jordi12100 suggested it is good pratice that you check errors while you connecting to database or executing queries.

You can do it like this:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("$server", "$user", "$pass", "$webdb") or die( "Error:" . mysqli_connect_error());

mysqli_query($link, $query) or die ("Error:" . mysqli_error($link));
```

This can give you idea what you did wrong.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Major Help; I'm getting used to mysqli and having something give me error numbers will help drastically.

Answer (score 1):

Probarly an error in your query.
Catch the error with mysqli_error();